# Handle default value for a property in faces custom converter

Tags: jsf

I couldn't manage to find any documentation on how to manage the  tag on my custom Converter. I read many examples / tutos pointing out this tag, but when I apply it the same way I see in examples, the default value is never set to my absent-property, leaving it instead with the "deafault" null value.. or any value I set it to in the constructor (which is obviously a duplicate and thus I cannot considerate it a proper solution ).

If anyone has any tip about this....

To show out, the converter -whose property' default value is never 'set'- and its tag look like this.

faces-config :

```
<converter>
    <converter-id>com.converter.currency</converter-id>
    <converter-class>com.somedomain.converters.CurrencyConverter</converter-lass>
    <property>
        <property-name>nbDecimal</property-name>
        <property-class>java.lang.Integer</property-class>
        <default-value>2</default-value>
    </property>
</converter>
```

taglib:

```
<tag>
    <tag-name>convertCurrency</tag-name>
    <converter>
        <converter-id>com.converter.currency</converter-id>
        <handler-class>com.somedomain.converters.CurrencyHandler</handler-class>
    </converter>
</tag>
```

CurrencyHandler :

```
private final TagAttribute nbDecimal;

public CurrencyHandler(ConverterConfig config) {
    super(config);
    this.nbDecimal= this.getAttribute("nbDecimal");
}
// ...
```

CurrencyConverter :

```
private Integer nbDecimal; // + getter / setter

public CurrencyConverter() {
    super();
}

public void init() {
    Integer nbDecimal = getNbDecimal();
    if (nbDecimal != null) {
        setMinFractionDigits(nbDecimal);
        setMaxFractionDigits(nbDecimal);
    } else {
        // this is where I could set them to default, which I don't want since it would not use the <default-value> in converter description
        // unless that is the point where my mistake comes from...
    }
}

public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {//...
}

public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {//...
}
/**
 * 
 */
public Integer getNbDecimal() {
    ELContext elContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
    if (getExpression() != null) {
        Integer nbDecimal = (Integer) getExpression().getValue(elContext);
        return nbDecimal;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It works exact as designed. You need play with `value` parameter in `getAsObject` or `getAsString` methods.

Comment: Though I understand how to play with the value parameter, I don't undestand how I can have "nbDecimal" be set to its default value (the one I set in the faces-config file) when it is actually null.... since it is null everytime I add no "nbDecimal" property to my tag (<some input><mycie:convertCurrency /></some inpur>)

Comment: `init` method is not called in `CurrencyConverter` constructor. It means nbDecimal is always null.